Яндекс.mapkit flutter Как сделать что бы остановки и общественные транспорты было видно на карте?
Всем привет!
Как сделать что бы остановки и общественные транспорты было видно на карте?
Как могу получать их список из карты и остановки один транспорта?
Приложению пилим на flutter, пакет yandex_mapkit

Указанный вами сторонний пакет мы не поддерживаем. Следует использовать официальный пакет.
Вы можете делать поисковые запросы ‘Public transport stops’ чтобы получить координаты нужных остановок и отображать их на карте. Отдельного метода для предоставления всех остановок общественного транспорта в населенном пункте нет.
